# Accessing Local storage in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

How to explore files in Windows Phone 8 (emulator & device) local storage. 
Is there any tool.

ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.ToString()

is the path where i've copied my files using simple copy function but i was unable find the files.

Comment: Files in the sense, are you talking about files which you've stored in?

Answer (score 0):

The `Windows Phone Power Tools` are a natural extension to the developer tools that come with the Windows Phone SDK. Instead of allowing you to only install developer xaps the Power Tools let you test update scenarios by allowing you to update an existing developer app. Instead of having to step through the `IsolatedStorage` file browser on the command line, the Power Tools provide a GUI to allow you to interact with your applications and its files .

You can Doownload it from [here](http://wptools.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I've already tried to open the file from power tools but my file was not found in the isolated storage.

Answer (score 0):

Matter of preference but I'd recommend IsoStoreSpy https://isostorespy.codeplex.com/